# How to compare two different size array and give color in UICollectionviewcell as per compare?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift3

I have to compare the arrays below with each other. But I get index out of range error in the for loop as well as in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. How do I compare these arrays and assign 3 different colours in `UICollectionviewcell`. The three arrays have different sizes?

```
{
"success": 1,
"time_slots": [
"10:00",
"10:15",
"10:30",
"10:45",
"11:00",
"11:15",
"11:30",
"11:45",
"12:00",
"12:15",
"12:30",
"12:45",
"13:00",
"13:15",
"13:30",
"13:45",
"14:00",
"14:15",
"14:30",
"14:45",
"15:00",
"15:15",
"15:30",
"15:45",
"16:00",
"16:15",
"16:30",
"16:45",
"17:00",
"17:15",
"17:30",
"17:45",
"18:00",
"18:15",
"18:30",
"18:45",
"19:00",
"19:15",
"19:30",
"19:45",
"20:00",
"20:15",
"20:30",
"20:45",
"21:00",
"21:15"
],
"booked_time_slots": [

],
"blocked_time_slots": [
"18:15",
"18:30",
"18:45",
"19:00",
"19:15",
"11:15",
"11:30",
"11:45",
"12:00"
],
"staff_detail": {
    "staffId": "6",
    "fname": "James Keri",
    "image": ""
    }
}
```

I am getting `Index out of range` error in the following code in my `cellForRow`:

```
var arrayOfSlotTime = [String]()
var arrayOfBlockTime = [String]() 
let stringFirst = arrayOfSlotTime[indexPath.row] as? String
let stringSecond = arrayOfBlockTime[indexPath.row] as? String
if stringFirst == stringSecond {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Constant.color.theamColor
} else { 
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Constant.color.blue
}
```

Comment: What are you doing in _cellForRow_ method? Please share _tableViewDataSource_.

Comment: You already have the answer. When the arrays are of different sizes you can't compare them.

Comment: Any alternate would be a hack and would require extra care.

Comment: Please add your `cellForRow` and for loop code as an edit in the answer and if possible please highlight the line where you get error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, that you are just creating two empty array, and than trying to access to its elements.

When you do this:

```
var arrayOfSlotTime = [String]()
var arrayOfBlockTime = [String]()
```

Both array has a count of zero, it contains no elements. And than when u this:

```
let stringFirst = arrayOfSlotTime[indexPath.row] as? String
let stringSecond = arrayOfBlockTime[indexPath.row] as? String
```

You are trying to access the element to whatever the value of `indexPath.row`. However, your containers are empty, there are no elements in it, therefore you crash with `Index out of range` error.

I assume `arrayOfSlotTime` and `arrayOfBlockTime` should come from somewhere else, and should not be empty for sure.

**EDIT:**

If the array contains the values from the JSON in the beginning of your question, just look at file. `time_slots` i assume is `arrayOfSlotTime` has 45 items, while `blocked_time_slots` is `arrayOfBlockTime` has 8 items.

When you access `indexPath.row` with the value of 8,  `arrayOfBlockTime` crashes with `Index out of range`, because it has elements from `[0...7]`

If you wanna do some transformation on the cells based on the two arrays has the same value at a given `indexPath`, do the following:

```
// Lets create the first string with the rigth indexPath value
let slotTime = arrayOfSlotTime[indexPath.row] as? String ?? ""
// Check if arrayOfBlockTime has the slotTime at the indexPath, and apply the color to a new variable 
let backgroundColor = arrayOfBlockTime.contains(slotTime) ? Constant.color.theamColor : Constant.color.blue
// Assign the background color
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
```

Comment: no no,I am giving example only,and comment space is less.So i thought any one imagine above given values in that arrays."time_slots": [] = arrayOfSlotTime  and
"blocked_time_slots": [] = arrayOfBlockTime has that values.

Comment: Thanks danee ,I got my answer.And I got my colors for three different arrays.